# Can someone help me derive this equation?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have read this paper [Translation-based Recommendations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02410.pdf) and I have some question about the derivation. I'm not familiar with the derivative of vector.

I want to derive $$\frac{\partial (\hat{p}_u,_i,_j - \hat{p}_u,_i,_j{\prime})}{\partial \Theta}$$ 
for all of the model parameters $$\Theta = \{\beta_{i} , \vec{\gamma_i},\vec{t_u}, \vec{t} \}$$

where $$\hat{p}_u,_i,_j$$ is a shorthand of 
$$Prob(j | u,i) \propto \beta_{j} - d(\vec{\gamma_i}+\vec{t_u} + \vec{t},\vec{\gamma_j})$$

Can anyone help me to derive this? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's better to write the math in the question directly using MathJax rather than linking to images.

Comment: @littleO thank you. I have already edited it.